# How to optimize T-SQL UI queries

Tags: sql-server, user-interface, optimization, indexing

I have UI form which shows to user different aggregate information (fact, plan etc. - 6 different T-SQL queries run in parallel). Execution of pure SQL queries takes up to 3 seconds. 
I use stored procedures with parameters, but there is no problem - call of SPs takes absolutely the same time. 
Here I use example of one table and one query, another 5 queries and tables have the same structure. I use MS SQL Server 2012, it's possible to upgrade up to 2014 if any optimization reason.

Now I try to find all possible ways to improve it. And it should be only SQL ways.

Aggregate table structure:

```
create table dbo.plan_Total(
  VersionId int not null,
  WarehouseId int not null,
  ChannelUnitId int not null,
  ProductId] int not null,
  Month date not null,
  Volume float not null,
 constraint PK_Total primary key clustered 
(VersionId asc, WarehouseId asc, ChannelUnitId asc, ProductId asc, Month asc)) on PRIMARY
```

SP query structure:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.plan_GetTotals
    @versionId INT, 
    @geoIds ID_LIST READONLY, -- lists from UI filters
    @productIds ID_LIST READONLY,
    @channelUnitIds ID_LIST READONLY
AS
begin

    SELECT Id INTO #geos 
    FROM @geoIds

    SELECT Id INTO #products
    FROM @productIds

    SELECT Id INTO #channels
    FROM @channelUnitIds

    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Geos ON #geos(Id)
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_Products ON #products(Id)
    CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ChannelUnits ON #channels(Id)

    SELECT Month, SUM(Volume) AS Volume 
    FROM plan_Total t
    JOIN #geos g ON t.WarehouseId = g.Id
    JOIN #products p ON t.ProductId = p.Id
    JOIN #channels cu ON t.ChannelUnitId = cu.Id
    WHERE VersionId = @versionId
    GROUP BY Month
    ORDER BY Month -- no any performance impact

END
```

Approx. execution time 600-800 ms. Time of another queries almost the same.
How can I dramatically decrease execution time? Is it possible?

What I've done already:

```
- Try columnstore indexes (clustered is not good because foreign key problem);
- Disable of non-clustered columnstore index is not solution, because in some tables need to update data online (user can change information);
- Rebuild all current indexes;
- Can't gather all tables in one.
```

Here is actual plan link:

[Actual execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmbjh.jpg) - for this plan i add real tables in joins instead of temp tables.

BR, thanks for any help!

Comment: can you please include execution plan

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered not asking not joining channel, product etc.?

At least channels - if you do not have 10.000 you can just load them "on demand" or "on application start" and cache them. This is a client side dictionary lookup.

Also Month, SUM(Volume)..... consider precalculating this, making a materialized view. Calculating this on demand is not what reporting should do and goes against data warehousing best practices.

All your solutions will not change that - they do not address the real problem: too much processing in the query.

Comment: Thx for comment
1.How is it possible not to ask parameters? This select works when user choose filters on user form. The set of parameters always different.
2. It's not only a calculation reason. Because when I bind joins (just for testing) to database tables it works twice faster or more.

Comment: Simple. DO not join in the query. Load them separate, then merge in memory. Also possibly significanly reduces the network traffic ;)

Comment: I think it's not possible to load it in memory because: a) I have 6 diff. queries on 6 tables, almost each table have more than 10 mln. rows. b) In this form user not only observe info, but can change multiplier and after we need to update tables rows.

Comment: You have 10 million CHANNELS? and you update the channels from this? Well, at least the number of channels is unusual - I doubt walmart have 10 million channels, or any retailer in the world.

Comment: Nope, sorry if I can't say it good in English. I mean I have 10 mln. rows in totals tables. I have approx. 250 warehouses, 150 products, 80 channels and 10 versions of plan, fact, forecast etc. User can choose any combination and after wee need to take volume summary by month for each table. Sure I have all channels, whrs and products in my filters in UI, but i never know what set of this parameters user need right now. Each form update I need to send this set to database and take data related to it. What do I need to put in memory in this case?

Comment: Well, noone said to preload TOTALS - i said to not join and preload the others. products, channels, warhouses can be joined in the program against a dictionary. This makes the query a LOT easier.

Comment: Yes I'am thinking how I can join all this parameters in UI and send to DB only one parameter... process is in progress :)

Comment: I have been doing that in other applications loading lookup tables of a million objects - with a nice lazy load mechanism that would load any object on "first needed" basis if missed during the initial load (as they can be added during the day). Loading time was half a second - which was nicely hidden because it happened at program start async ;) the joins go a lot easier, less data on the network etc.

Answer (score 0):

See if this way works better

- Create the `TABLE` type to have a `PRIMARY KEY`
- Specify option `RECOMPILE`: force compiler to include cardinality of `TABLE` variables
- Specify option `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`: prevent parameter sniffing for `@versionId`

---

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ID_LIST AS TABLE (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY
);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.plan_GetTotals
    @versionId INT, 
    @geoIds ID_LIST READONLY,
    @productIds ID_LIST READONLY,
    @channelUnitIds ID_LIST READONLY
AS
    SELECT 
        Month,
        SUM(Volume) AS Volume 
    FROM 
        plan_Total AS t
        INNER JOIN @geoIds AS g ON g.Id=t.WarehouseId
        INNER JOIN @productIds AS p ON p.Id=t.ProductId
        INNER JOIN @channelUnitIds AS c ON c.Id=t.ChannelUnitId
    WHERE 
        t.VersionId=@versionId
    GROUP BY 
        Month
    ORDER BY 
        Month
    OPTION(RECOMPILE, OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN);
GO
```

Comment: Thx for comment. 1)I already use it. 2) and 3) doesn't help but I add it in my query. Thx

Comment: @MrAndrewSmith That's a pitty. The execution plan looks way simpler than what you have though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here I just show what I can find and how I increased speed of mu query.

List of addins:

1. Best way is to add Clustered columnstore index. For that you need to delete FK's but you can use triggers for example. This increase the query up to 3-4 times.
2. How you can see I use temp tables in query joins. I've changed one join (doesn't matter which) to IN operand like this "and t.productid in (select id from @productids)" it increased query pure speed twice.

This two made most impact to the query. Below I want to show the final query:

```
select [month], sum(volume) as volume 
from #geos g
left join dbo.plan_Total t on t.warehouseid = g.id
join #channels cu on t.channelunitid = cu.id
where versionid = @versionid 
  and t.productid in (select id from @productids)
group by [month]
order by [Month]
```

With this changes I decrease query execution time from 0.8 to 0.2 ms.